# C# How to draw line with direction

Tags: c#

I want to make a line with direction using Cos and Sin, but i got a problem, the object position is **1, 0** and the pencil position is **0, 5**. So the pencil can draw only diagonal, and straight line. The Direction using degree angle.

Here's the code C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int x = 0;
     int y = 5;
     int targetX = 1;
     int targetY = 0;

     DrawLine(x, y, targetX, targetY);
}

//This is the Pencil like an object...
static void DrawLine(int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY)
{
     while (!false)
     {
          if (x != targetX && y != targetY)
          {
                     double direction = Math.Atan2(targetX, targetY) * (180 / Math.PI);

                     int changeX = (int)Math.Sin((float)direction);
                     int changeY = (int)Math.Cos((float)direction);
                     // check if the change x and change y is -0!
                     if (changeX == -0) changeX = -1;
                     else if (changeY == -0) changeY = -1;

                     x += changeX;
                     y += changeY;
                     Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                     Console.WriteLine("#");
          }
          else
          {
              x = 0;
              y = 0;
          }
     }
}
```

I use Console Applications no the Windows Forms App from c#.
The target x and y is from the object position.
There's no error, but can you fix it?

- Hopefully this is helpful...

The Pencil object does cannot draw to the target only the Pencil can draw diagonal and straight line itself.

Edit:

-> **If is there any problem on my page, i will edit it again**...

Here's the image clue:
[image]

Comment: This question doesn't contain anything about using Visual Studio (the application). Please do not add irrelevant tags as it just wastes other people's time to remove them.

Comment: What happens when you step through your code with the debugger? Do you find any problems with the values of your variables at each step? Also, you might want to look at implementing a line drawing algorithm if you're doing diagonal lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

Comment: What is Console C#? What is the Pencil object?

Comment: There are errors in your code, for starters your code does not compile. What are x[i] and y[i] ? Where are they set in your code?

Comment: oh wait, my bad. ill edit it again...

Comment: Done, the x[i], and y[i] it's from my game, so i'll copy on my game c# and paste it on stack overflow.

Comment: sin and cos return values in the range [-1, +1]. so casting them to integers is going to produce a zero unless the the value is exactly +1 or -1, meaning only when vector is exactly parallel to the x or y axis.  (sin(angle), cos(angle)) produces (x, y) values on the unit circle.  So, any direction that is even slightly diagonal will set both `changeX` and `changeY` equal to zero.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the actual goal? A console is not a good way to display lines or any other kind of graphics. Note that you can draw lines and other shapes to a bitmap even in a console application, and that would be way simpler than implementing a proper line drawing algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

```
double direction = Math.Atan2(targetX, targetY);

int changeX = (int)Math.Sin(direction);
int changeY = (int)Math.Cos(direction);
```

Comment: @unobatbayar Probably because code only answers are not very helpful. The answer should explain how this fixes the problem.